# How to make a x column table in mysql?

Tags: c++, mysql, sql

So I want to make a table in MYSQL (using c++) with about 128 columns each on representing an INT.

I don't know the syntax to make a 129 column row (1 for id 128 for each int)

Kinda like an array: int myArray[128];

CREATE TABLE SIFTFEATUES(ID INT not null, myArray[128] INT) would be Ideal or something close
where I don't have to write out each column name.

Comment: *WHY* in the world would you want to design a table like that for? How do you plan on referencing the 114th int in that table if you haven't explicitly named it? Give us an idea of what you're trying to do and maybe there's a better way than this.

Comment: Geez So many downvotes so fast. I just want some help... I am not a database programer.

I have SIFT features from an image. Each features is represented in an array of 128 ints. I want to store all the features I extract from an Image in an sql database What is the best way of going about doing that if having 128 columns is out of the question.

Comment: Without having an insane amount of rows. I figured columns made way more sense.

Comment: @Jay: Your post seems to request new code, while there is no code already attempted.  The first comment here also explains that.

Comment: @Jamal: Huh? I am just asking for create table syntax or an idea as to why the way I am think about it is wrong.


There is no code to give because I don't know how to write it...
I am asking for an Idea as to how I would store 128 ints in a single row. Does not matter what the code is or what the application does. This does not mean I would need 128 columns if there is a better way of doing this.

Comment: You have taken a wrong turn somewhere. Back up, and start again.

Comment: An insane amount of rows makes more sense than even 30 columns

Comment: @Strawberry: Ok thats fine. But why? Interested here in learning... Not just to blindly except something

Comment: You could look into data serialization to store the array of ints in a single column. Since you apparently don't need to look up any of the individual values of the array at runtime (but instead need the whole thing if conditions are met), that would be a reasonable solution. I'm not sure how to serialize in c++, but others here may be able to chime in as to whether or not that would work.

Comment: A database table is not a spreadsheet. They may have superficial similarities but they're fundamentally different concepts. See normalization.

Comment: @MichaelTodd: Thank you, that makes sense. I don't need to look at each element at running time. The only reason I put them in a sql db is so I can push all that information into memory when I need it. Each 128 array that is.

Answer (score 0):

To have a table with 128 columns defined, you need to "write out" each column name. Each column in the table gets a name, a datatype, and other optional attributes.

In order to retrieve data from the column, it has to be referenced by name; the same is true for inserting and updating the contents of the column.

---

(I put "write out" in double quotes, because it's very simple task to generate a text file of 128 lines of a table definition that vary only by name. (It's not necessary to type each line.)

```
, col001 int
, col002 int
, ...
, col128 int
```

---

Absent any other information about your use case, what you are trying to accomplish, it's nearly impossible to make any sort of recommendation.

Comment: I am trying to make a table for each Image feature type. So lets say I extract features from an image. (Surf or SIFT) they have different ways of defining a feature. I.e 64 int descriptor or a 128 int descriptor. I want a table where the ID is linked to the image I am extracting for and the array would be for the specific feature int array[128] or int arry[64] what would be a good way of going about doing this then

Answer (score 0):

A table should be use for data persistence, thus not to be used like an array (with obvious exceptions). With that said I see two scenarios:

1) You want to use it like a temporary data structure, which I strongly do not recommend, unless for medical reasons.

2) You want to keep that table, for which I'd use a text editor or even MS Excel and create a macro to create the `CREATE TABLE`statement with your 128 columns.